# ffmpeg applies incorrect SMPTE170M transfer function?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg to apply the SMPTE170M OETF to example input. I've tried:

```
# 1
ffmpeg -y -framerate 25 -i linear.png -sws_flags accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int \
  -vf "zscale=min=gbr:tin=linear:m=gbr:t=smpte170m" out1.png

#2
ffmpeg -y -framerate 25 -i linear.png -sws_flags accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int \
  -vf "colorspace=iall=bt709:itrc=linear:all=bt709" out2.png
```

With #1 the transformed values are all too high compared to a manual calculation. Eg, for a channel value of 200 the spec says:

```
V=200/255
1.099*V^.45 - 0.099 = 0.886185722 (aka 226)
```

but ffmpeg will produce 231. It produces this value given the same input regardless of channel.

With #2, the produced value changes per channel. I know there's an RGB->YUV->RGB conversion being added around the `colorspace` filter but I'm not sure why that would cause such significant differences. E.g. for an input value of 200/255 in each channel I get:

```
0,0: (237,62,0)  #ED3E00  srgb(237,62,0)
0,0: (0,208,0)  #00D000  srgb(0,208,0)
0,0: (0,46,232)  #002EE8  srgb(0,46,232)
0,0: (226,226,226)  #E2E2E2  srgb(226,226,226)
```

Note that the greyscale value is actually the correct value I'm expecting.

How do I fix one/both incantations to produce the expected results?

Comment: re #1: the conversion is carried out by libzimg,, so it should be queried there. Of the 2 commands, this is your best bet.

Comment: re #2: I'm confident that conversion of linear RGB to YUV or the converse has not been extensively tested for correctness. ffmpeg is mostly used with weighted signals as that is the norm. And in any case, neither command relies on swscale for pixel conversion, so sws_flags is inert.

Comment: It looks like `zscale` filter uses the [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Transformation) gamma transfer function, that is close to smpte170m, but not the same (the accurate result of sRGB is 229). There is also an option to set `agamma=false`, but it doesn't help a lot (output value is 230).